# bundle install: TypeError: Arguments to path.resolve must be strings

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, gemfile

I get this error when trying to use bundle install - does anyone have any idea what might be causing it?

```
$ bundle install
path.js:439
      throw new TypeError('Arguments to path.resolve must be strings');
            ^
TypeError: Arguments to path.resolve must be strings
    at Object.posix.resolve (path.js:439:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/script/bin/bundle:38:24)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
```

Example gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'capybara'
```

Comment: Google is full of ideas

Comment: What gem are you trying to install?  And have you tried to uninstall bundler and reinstall it?

Comment: I would recommend posting your Gemfile in your question, so people can see if there is a syntax error or not.

Comment: @fl00r, I did try Google first but can't find anything bundler related (googling brings me back to this post now!).

Comment: @Chris I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling. I get the error with any gems, added example to OP

Comment: @user3468025 I would add to your question what OS your running, and the software your using to manage your rubies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is rather odd but while trying something I accidentally typo'ed bundler install (rather than bundle install) and it worked...

```
$ bundler install
    Resolving dependencies...
    Using builder 3.2.2
    Using mime-types 2.6.1
    Using mini_portile 0.6.2
    Using nokogiri 1.6.6.2
    Using rack 1.6.4
    Using rack-test 0.6.3
    Using xpath 2.0.0
    Using capybara 2.4.4
    Using ffi 1.9.10
    Using childprocess 0.5.6
    Using cmdparse 3.0.1
    Using multi_json 1.11.2
    Using gherkin 2.12.2
    Using cucumber-core 1.2.0
    Using diff-lcs 1.2.5
    Using multi_test 0.1.2
    Using cucumber 2.0.2
    Using unf_ext 0.0.7.1
    Using unf 0.1.4
    Using domain_name 0.5.24
    Using highline 1.7.3
    Using http-cookie 1.0.2
    Using json 1.8.3
    Using net-http-persistent 2.9.4
    Using net-ssh 2.9.2
    Using net-ssh-gateway 1.2.0
    Using netrc 0.10.3
    Using parallel 1.6.1
    Using parallel_tests 0.15.0
    Using require_all 1.3.2
    Using rest-client 1.8.0
    Using rspec-support 3.3.0
    Using rspec-core 3.3.2
    Using rspec-expectations 3.3.1
    Using rspec-mocks 3.3.2
    Using rspec 3.3.0
    Using rubyzip 1.1.7
    Using sauce_whisk 0.0.18
    Using websocket 1.2.2
    Using selenium-webdriver 2.46.2
    Using sauce 3.1.3
    Using sauce-connect 3.1.0
    Using watir-webdriver 0.8.0
    Using bundler 1.10.6
    Bundle complete! 9 Gemfile dependencies, 44 gems now installed.
    Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed
```

But still when I type bundle install:

```
$ bundle install
path.js:439
      throw new TypeError('Arguments to path.resolve must be strings');
            ^
TypeError: Arguments to path.resolve must be strings
    at Object.posix.resolve (path.js:439:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/script/bin/bundle:38:24)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
```